# Not able to do password-free access to remote machine!

Tags: ssh

When I run

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ rlogin 109.202.101.166
```

it promps me for password as below:

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ rlogin 109.202.101.166
ravbholua@109.202.101.166's password:
```

To make password free access, I created a file /etc/hosts.equiv
in the remote machine (ravi.com) as below:

```
root@ravi:/etc# cat hosts.equiv
localhost
42.110.54.211
root@ravi:/etc#
```

But still whenever I run the above command to login to this remote
machine, it asks for password.

Additionally, I also created .rhosts file in my same like-to-like account
in remote machine in home dir. as below:

```
ravbholua@ravi:~$ cat .rhosts
localhost
42.110.54.211
ravbholua@ravi:~$
```

What may be the problem that I am not able to have password-free access.

One important point to be noted:
To know what's my internet IP address is, I got from the below two sites (both gave the same IP address)

```
http://www.ipchicken.com/
http://whatismyip.org/
```

You may please refer to the below link where I had asked for the same query but 
couldn't get resolved.
[not-able-to-do-password-free-access-to-remote-machine](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/not-able-to-do-password-free-access-to-remote-machine-4175475825/)

---

**Edit**: I ran:

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ sudo scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub rs:.ssh/authorized_keys
```

as without sudo, it messaged:permission denied. Then I tried both

```
sudo ssh rs
```

and

```
ssh rs
```

Still I was prompted for password. I entered my remote server after entering password and found the file that was transferred in /root/.ssh as shown ahead.

```
root@ravi:~/.ssh# ls                             
authorized_keys known_hosts                                      
root@ravi:~/.ssh#
```

Please note rs is an alias for my remote server.

Comment: What distribution are you using? Almost no one ships a real [rlogin](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1282) by default any longer because it is horribly insecure. OpenSSH sometimes provides an alias for ssh called `rlogin` which never even looks at `.rhosts` because that's part of the horrible insecurity. See the answer by @maxschlepzig for how to remote shell properly. If you have the option of installing an old-fashioned RFC1282 `rlogind`, don't, It's a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [ssh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) to configure password-less login to a remote computer.

It is just (on computer a):

```
$ ssh-keygen # use an empty password!
$ scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub computer_b:.ssh/authorized_keys
```

That's it.

Now you can do a

```
$ ssh computer_b
```

without having to enter a password.

You can optionally configure things like:

- host alias for computer_b, e.g. to be able to enter `ssh alias`
- set public-key authentication as default for that host/alias
- allow only public-key authentication (for the sshd on computer_b)

Unless you can't use ssh, it seems to be much more convenient to setup than rlogin.

Plus, ssh protects you against [main-in-the-middle attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) and [eavesdropping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eavesdropping).

### Troubleshooting

Make sure that the `~/.ssh` has the right permissions (on both systems) - i.e. is only accessible by your user - otherwise ssh ignores it. That means only `rwx------` for the directory and `rw-------` for the files. Use `ls -l` and `ls -ld` to verify this.

Make sure that the remote `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` contains the correct public key. Verify via:

```
$ ssh computer_b cat '~/.ssh/authorized_keys' # remote
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub # local
```

If the setup does not work like this, perhaps you have to explicitly configure the client side, i.e. adding something like this to `.ssh/config`:

```
Host computer_b
Hostname some_hostname
User juser
PreferredAuthentications publickey # makes testing easier
IdentitiesOnly yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

For diagnosing issues it is also useful to add `-v` to `ssh` call, e.g.:

```
$ ssh -v computer_b
```

Comment: Oh! it didn't work.

Comment: @Ravi, added some infos on troubleshooting ssh issues.

Comment: Great it worked. Thanks! But one point: I tried it for root and not an ordinary user. Because for the ordinary user (user-name: ravbholua), the directory ~ravbholua/.ssh is owned by root.              `root@ravi:/home/ravbholua# ls -ld .ssh
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Sep 10 08:09 .ssh
root@ravi:/home/ravbholua# `                                Now for this to work for the user named 'ravbholua',how to proceed. Shall I make root to renounce the ownership to the user named ravbholua. Also what may be the reason that the .ssh directory under the user ravbholua has root as the owner

Comment: @ maxschlepzig Hi! Now ordinary user (ravbholua) is also enjoying password free login. root renounced the ownership of the .ssh directory to the user ravbholua and hence achieved what was required. Thanks a lot for your asssitance. Great!!